# Is computer name a hostname that I can point it to an IP?

Tags: networking, ip, hostname, computer-name

On my Windows7, when I get into the properties of My Computer, I can see that my computer name is compname123. It seems that when I ping or connect (say remote access) to this computer from another computer, I can just write in the hostname compname123 without having to write the IP address. In this sense, the compname123, which is a computer name, is almost like a meaningful hostname that will resolve to the IP address automatically.

But is this really a hostname?

I notice that sometimes when the IP changes, I will not be able to connect from another computer using the computer name for a while. Somehow, though, the computer name will automatically reflect the new IP after some time.

Is my computer name a hostname? Can I even say I want my computer name to be stuck to a certain IP, especially in the case when I'm going to use a static IP? If so, how can I do this?

Comment: Do you know much about DNS...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> is this really a hostname?

The windows computer name is distinct but can, in some circumstances, act as a DNS hostname.

Windows has it's own traditional system of naming which is not DNS. This allows windows computers to communicate by name over TCP/IP even when a DNS server is not present. See *NetBIOS naming services*.

However when a Windows client obtains an IP-address from a Windows DHCP server in a Windows domain, typically the client computer name is then registered as a host name in the DNS service.

So the computer name isn't really a hostname until it has been registered as such with a naming service.

> when the IP changes, I will not be able to connect from another computer using the computer name for a while.

Look up *ARP caching*.

Open a command prompt and enter `arp -a` and `arp -?`.

> I want my computer name to be stuck to a certain IP,

Use a *DHCP reservation* in your DHCP server (based on MAC-address of primary network interface).